# Populate ListBox on ComboBox selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to populate a list box with rows that match a combobox selection (in column A)

I keep getting this error when i reach a record that has a match in the worksheet `run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)':Type mismatch`

I am trying to search the range for matching values, then add them to the listbox, if there are none, do nothing. But it seems when there is a match I get this error, VBA not my thing, a little confused. Please help.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Set Rng = Sheets("ActionItems").Range("A2:A50").Find(what:=Me.ComboBox3.Value)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        ListBox3.Value = ""
    Else
       ListBox3.AddItem Sheets("ActionItems").Range("B2:C8")
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox3.AddItem`:

- For a single-column list box, adds one item (one cell) to the list
- For a multicolumn list box, adds a row to the list

so you cannot add multiple cells from `Range("B2:C8")`

There are 2 options:

---

Work with the `.ListFillRange` which takes a string (the address of a range)

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("ActionItems")

        Set rng = .Range("A2:A5").Find(What:=Me.ComboBox3.Value)

        ListBox3.ListFillRange = IIf(rng Is Nothing, vbNullString, .Range("B2:C8").Address)

    End With
End Sub
```

---

Or:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Dim rng As Range, itm As Variant, i As Long

    With Sheets("ActionItems")

        Set rng = .Range("A2:A5").Find(What:=Me.ComboBox3.Value)

        'ListBox3.Clear    'This depends on how you populated the listbox
        ListBox3.ListFillRange = vbNullString

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each itm In .Range("B2:C8")
                ListBox3.AddItem itm
            Next
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul, I have however gone in a different direction since then. I couldn't get the combobox to work as I wanted it to. I have since change this to a textbox as below. What I am trying to do is allow the user to type into the textbox and have the listbox display any matching results, if any. The new code I have will find a single result and highlight it, but I can't get the listbox to filter visible results, not sure how to do this.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
        'searches ListBox3 for match and hightlights result. Need to filter results.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sFind As String

    sFind = Me.TextBox3.Text

    If Len(sFind) = 0 Then
        Me.ListBox3.ListIndex = -1
        Me.ListBox3.TopIndex = 0
    Else
        For i = 0 To Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1
            If UCase(Left(Me.ListBox3.List(i), Len(sFind))) = UCase(sFind) Then
                Me.ListBox3.TopIndex = i
                Me.ListBox3.ListIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```